# Video is playing in Simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayerviewcontroller

Video is playing in simulator but not on real device. Its stored in the local file path. After choosen the video from gallery, I'm compressing the video and storing the data in document directory. Here is the code.

video Compression:

```
- (void)compressVideo:(NSURL*)inputURL
        outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
          handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler
{
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
   AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
   AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
   exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
   exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
  [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
  {
     handler(exportSession);
  }];
}
```

Stored the compressed video here:

```
[self compressVideo:sourceURL outputURL:uploadURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *completion) {
 if (completion.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
    NSData *newDataForUpload = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uploadURL];
   // ...
 }
];
```

And this is sourceURL and UploadURL

```
NSURL *sourceURL = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
NSURL* uploadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temporaryPreview.mov"]];
```

Comment: What is the `uploadURL`? Since you can't write in NSBundle, but if I remember correctly, Simulator allows it.

Comment: @Larme check it now. I have added it